# Java code to pass parent class name to the child class at runtime

Tags: java

I have one class C  which i have extended with another parent class P class as per below code

```
public class C extends P{//code here}
```

Now i need to send class name of C to called class P, so that it can be used by the class P.

Is this possible at the runtime to pass the class name of C to P?

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Huh?  Why do you need the name?  Not a clue what you are asking.

Comment: `pass parent class name to the child class` or `pass the class name of C to P`? Pick one

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getClass().getName(); // get subclass name within superclass
super.getClass().getName(); // get superclass name within subclass
```